# Exchange 2010 FQDN name

Tags: exchange

We just built an Exchange 2010 server, just got outbound mail flow working.

Our internal Active Directory domain name is NFTKC
Our External domain name is:  newfrontiertech.com

When I send an e-mail to my Yahoo or Windows Live account the domain name show up as:  nftkc.newfrontiertech.com

Really would like to be just "newfrontiertech.com

Any ideas?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Tried that, then rebooted the mail server.  Still comes through as nftkc.newfrontiertech.com

Comment: what part comes through?  Can you update your post with the header and the part you don't like?  You might be referring to something different than what we are thinking you meant.

Comment: Received: from NewFrontierTech.com ([99.31.50.30]) by COL0-MC2-F22.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
  Fri, 26 Jul 2013 10:55:18 -0700
Received: from NFTKC-DC.NFTKC.NewFrontierTech.com
 ([fe80::ac17:8d28:952c:ba4d]) by NFTKC-DC.NFTKC.NewFrontierTech.com
 ([fe80::ac17:8d28:952c:ba4d%11]) with mapi;
From: Matt Fitzsimmons <mfitzsimmons@nftkc.newfrontiertech.com>
To: "'fitzinator@live.com'" <fitzinator@live.com>
Subject: TEST
Thread-Topic: TEST

Comment: I would like the address to show as being from mfitzsimmons@newfrontiertech.com instead of mfitzsimmons@nftkc.newfrontiertech.com     Thanks for the help

Comment: That's totally different.  If you want your SMTP address to be @newfrontiertech.com you need to change it on your mailbox, either manually or with the recipient policy that is probably in place creating it as nftkc.newfrontiertech.com.

Comment: Managed to get it working but will need to go into Exchange Management Console and add a new e-mail address then uncheck the "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy" box then set the new address to "Set as Reply".  Seems like the long way around.   Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Correct you will have to uncheck the box if you don't want the policy to apply.  But why not get your policy to be that way for everyone?

Answer (score 3):

So change it.

Assuming no smart host or other hop after your Exchange server.

In the EMC under `Organization Configuration` then `Hub Transport` choose the `Send Connectors` tab.

Open the properties of the Send Connector and change the FQDN as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the FQDN on the default Send Connector's General properties tab.

Comment: mine has a pic. :)

Comment: Well you get extra credit then! :)